# Would asking for sailboats buildingplan resources be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can people ask questions like this on the great outdoors:

Am looking for a while for several buildingplans of wooden sailboats, especially Dutch wooden boats, anyone who knows good resources?

edit: See this post [Suited for The Great Outdoors or not?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6434/63196) at area51.SE

Therfore I think they should be.

Answer (score 6):

My answer would tend to be Yes.  Looking over sites that succeeded, it appears to me that they were VERY permissive in topics in the early stages while they built their community, then refined it down over time. Overflow followed this model, as well as Skeptics.  The cleanup period appears to cause a loss of some users, but being too proactive up front appears to lead to stillbirth.

Comment: Actually I want my topic in a separate stack. However that would be a very unlikely change for success. So having this stack as a 'mothering'-stack would be cool. As it adds to the change of success to both.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I believe there was a general "Boating" proposal on Area51, which was killed, so I don't think it will be any time soon for a sailboat building question to have its own site :(

Answer (score -1):

I would say no.

This site is about the Great Outdoors, yes, but not specifically about the building of a sailboat.  They are far too complex and probably deserve their own SE site (Marine/Boats in general).

Comment: There is a proposal: 'Recreational Boats' pending (requested name change 'Boat Craftsmanship' as that fits its description. However there is some misunderstanding at the area51 that boat building should belongs here.